# Does the trim on my sliding door need caulk?

Tags: exterior, trim, sliding-glass-door

Sliding door keeps leaking into the house when it rains, called Window company and all they did was re-caulk the door which didnt help. (I will be calling them again)

Since the trim on the exterior of the house isn't their problem, my question is, does this need caulk?

1. Top of the door trim

[image]

2. Side trim

[image]

Comment: The top should have Z-flashing which would go under the siding, then over the top of the wood trim.

Comment: I take it the trim at the top of the door is original and they did not install it, nor did it leak before the new door was installed? If it didn't leak, what was there before the door was installed?